# Android native crash on google pixel 6P only

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, native

Receiving a crash report on developer console, happened only with google Nexus 6P(angler) Android 8.0, running fine with ASUS Zenfone, Google Nexus 5, SAMSUNG Galaxy S4, S5, S6, S7 with Android 4.3 and above. I don't have any device so I could not reproduce the issue.

```
Cmd line: com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx
ABI: 'arm'
"Shutdown thread" sysTid=19746
#00 pc 00018d98  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01 pc 000b375d  /system/lib/libart.so(_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+88)
#02 pc 003620e3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList34WaitForOtherNonDaemonThreadsToExitEv+142)
#03 pc 00361ef9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadListD1Ev+136)
#04 pc 003366bd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7RuntimeD1Ev+1372)
#05 pc 002339f5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JII13DestroyJavaVMEP7_JavaVM+16)
#06 pc 000795a3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+590)
#07 pc 00001af7  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+762)
#08 pc 00017d35  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
#09 pc 00001724  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start+96)

"Binder:19746_1" sysTid=19759
#00 pc 000493a0  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0001ddef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+38)
#02 pc 00047f27  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+202)
#03 pc 00048035  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+8)
#04 pc 0004859f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+38)
#05 pc 0005eb25  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android10PoolThread10threadLoopEv+12)
#06 pc 0000d38d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+140)
#07 pc 00079889  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
#08 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#09 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"Binder:19746_2" sysTid=19760
#00 pc 000493a0  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0001ddef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+38)
#02 pc 00047f27  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+202)
#03 pc 00048035  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+8)
#04 pc 0004859f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+38)
#05 pc 0005eb25  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android10PoolThread10threadLoopEv+12)
#06 pc 0000d38d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+140)
#07 pc 00079889  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
#08 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#09 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"RenderThread" sysTid=19763
 #00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
 #01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
 #02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
 #03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
 #04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
 #05 pc 0003c253  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+402)
 #06 pc 0000d38d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+140)
 #07 pc 00079889  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
 #08 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
 #09 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"queued-work-loo" sysTid=19764
#00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
#01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
#02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
#04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
#05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
#06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
#07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
#08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
#09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
#10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
#11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
#12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
#13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
#14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
#15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
#16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"RenderThread" sysTid=19765
 #00 pc 00018d98  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
 #01 pc 0004764f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL24__pthread_cond_timedwaitP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tbPK8timespec+102)
 #02 pc 0004bf0d  /system/lib/libc++.so (_ZNSt3__118condition_variable4waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEE+8)
 #03 pc 000087cf  /system/lib/libhidlbase.so (_ZN7android8hardware7details17SynchronizedQueueINSt3__18functionIFvvEEEE8wait_popEv+42)
#04 pc 00008725  /system/lib/libhidlbase.so (_ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN7android8hardware7details10TaskRunner5startEjE3$_0EEEEEPvSD_+60)
#05 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#06 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"retrive" sysTid=19768
#00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
#01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
#02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
#04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
#05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
#06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
#07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
#08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
#09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
#10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
#11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
#12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
#13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
#14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
#15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
#16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"spp_channel" sysTid=19770
#00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
#01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
#02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
#04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
#05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
#06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
#07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
#08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
#09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
#10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
#11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
#12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
#13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
#14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
#15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
#16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"spp_listener" sysTid=19771
#00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
#01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
#02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
#04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
#05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
#06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
#07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
#08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
#09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
#10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
#11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
#12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
#13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
#14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
#15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
#16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"spp_write" sysTid=19772
 #00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
 #01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
 #02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
 #03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
 #04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
 #05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
#06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
 #07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
 #08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
 #09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
 #10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
 #11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
 #12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
 #13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
 #14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
 #15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
 #16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
 #17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

 "SyncCore Handle" sysTid=19775
 #00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
 #01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
 #02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
 #03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
 #04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
 #05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
 #06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
 #07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
 #08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
 #09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
 #10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
 #11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
 #12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
 #13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
 #14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
 #15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
 #16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
 #17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

  "SyncCore Handle" sysTid=19776
  #00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  #01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
  #02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
   #04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
   #05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
   #06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
 #07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
 #08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
 #09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
 #10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
 #11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
 #12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
 #13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
 #14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
 #15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
 #16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
 #17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

  "ConnectivityThr" sysTid=19777
#00 pc 00049264  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
#01 pc 0001b375  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+60)
#02 pc 0001b3a5  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#03 pc 000101eb  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+118)
#04 pc 000100dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+32)
#05 pc 000b6a6d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+24)
#06 pc 0075aea5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.app.NativeActivity.onWindowFocusChangedNative [DEDUPED]+92)
#07 pc 00dcf97f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+198)
#08 pc 00dca21d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.Looper.loop+428)
#09 pc 00ae9d8d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5bb000) (android.os.HandlerThread.run+508)
#10 pc 003dc1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
#11 pc 003e0755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
#12 pc 000ac2ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
#13 pc 003319cd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
#14 pc 00332841  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+320)
#15 pc 003500b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+892)
#16 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#17 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

"Binder:19746_3" sysTid=19778
#00 pc 000493a0  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0001ddef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+38)
#02 pc 00047f27  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+202)
#03 pc 00048035  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+8)
#04 pc 0004859f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+38)
#05 pc 0005eb25  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android10PoolThread10threadLoopEv+12)
#06 pc 0000d38d  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+140)
#07 pc 00079889  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+80)
#08 pc 00047c3f  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
#09 pc 0001af5d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

----- end 19746 -----

----- pid 796 at 2017-10-09 06:01:10 -----
Cmd line: system_server
Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:8.0.0/OPR5.170623.007/4302479:user/release-keys'
ABI: 'arm64'
Build type: optimized
Zygote loaded classes=4672 post zygote classes=4371
Intern table: 47428 strong; 1959 weak
JNI: CheckJNI is off; globals=3512 (plus 591 weak)
Libraries: /system/lib64/libandroid.so /system/lib64/libandroid_servers.so /system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so /system/lib64/libjnigraphics.so /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so /system/lib64/libwifi-service.so libjavacore.so libopenjdk.so (11)
Heap: 41% free, 25MB/43MB; 500726 objects
Dumping cumulative Gc timings
Start Dumping histograms for 98 iterations for concurrent copying
ProcessMarkStack:   Sum: 11.759s 99% C.I. 3.136ms-399.232ms Avg: 119.991ms             Max: 518.064ms
VisitConcurrentRoots:   Sum: 508.367ms 99% C.I. 1.985ms-14.028ms Avg: 5.187ms Max: 15.308ms
ScanImmuneSpaces:   Sum: 238.484ms 99% C.I. 0.774ms-5.869ms Avg: 2.433ms Max: 6.778ms
FlipOtherThreads:   Sum: 138.482ms 99% C.I. 0.233ms-7.594ms Avg: 1.413ms Max: 12.084ms
EnqueueFinalizerReferences: Sum: 81.571ms 99% C.I. 42us-5004us Avg: 832.357us Max: 5126us
ClearFromSpace: Sum: 80.583ms 99% C.I. 185us-2662us Avg: 822.275us Max: 2662us
EmptyRBMarkBitStack:    Sum: 65.551ms 99% C.I. 49us-2937.500us Avg: 668.887us Max: 3549us
VisitNonThreadRoots:    Sum: 63.675ms 99% C.I. 44us-1326.500us Avg: 649.744us Max: 1369us
SweepSystemWeaks:   Sum: 53.360ms 99% C.I. 42us-1430.500us Avg: 544.489us     Max: 1674us
ThreadListFlip: Sum: 48.651ms 99% C.I. 19us-13008us Avg: 496.438us Max: 22928us
ProcessReferences:  Sum: 36.081ms 99% C.I. 0.466us-1033.999us Avg: 184.086us Max: 2671us
ForwardSoftReferences:  Sum: 30.183ms 99% C.I. 6us-853us Avg: 307.989us Max: 964us
SweepLargeObjects:  Sum: 24.037ms 99% C.I. 10us-1553us Avg: 245.275us Max: 1661us
InitializePhase:    Sum: 22.445ms 99% C.I. 77us-1079.500us Avg: 229.030us Max: 1290us
MarkingPhase:   Sum: 22.388ms 99% C.I. 12us-4977us Avg: 228.448us Max: 6231us
RecordFree: Sum: 21.471ms 99% C.I. 118us-977.500us Avg: 219.091us Max: 1070us
GrayAllDirtyImmuneObjects:  Sum: 15.104ms 99% C.I. 55us-425.500us Avg: 154.122us Max: 438us
FlipThreadRoots:    Sum: 8.764ms 99% C.I. 2us-3544us Avg: 89.428us Max: 5696us
ClearRegionSpaceCards:  Sum: 6.245ms 99% C.I. 14us-428.500us Avg: 63.724us Max: 592us
ReclaimPhase:   Sum: 4.650ms 99% C.I. 5us-1055us Avg: 47.448us Max: 1285us
ResumeRunnableThreads:  Sum: 4.616ms 99% C.I. 5us-143us Avg: 47.102us Max: 143us
ResumeOtherThreads: Sum: 3.362ms 99% C.I. 1us-157us Avg: 34.306us Max: 157us
MarkZygoteLargeObjects: Sum: 3.087ms 99% C.I. 14us-227.500us Avg: 31.500us Max: 338us
(Paused)ClearCards: Sum: 2.421ms 99% C.I. 0.250us-49.813us Avg: 1.544us Max: 93us
SweepAllocSpace:    Sum: 1.643ms 99% C.I. 2us-110us Avg: 16.765us Max: 110us
MarkStackAsLive:    Sum: 1.348ms 99% C.I. 3us-47us Avg: 13.755us Max: 47us
(Paused)FlipCallback:   Sum: 1.206ms 99% C.I. 3us-69us Avg: 12.306us Max: 69us
SwapBitmaps:    Sum: 548us 99% C.I. 3us-27us Avg: 5.591us Max: 27us
Sweep:  Sum: 284us 99% C.I. 2us-8us Avg: 2.897us Max: 8us
UnBindBitmaps:  Sum: 32us 99% C.I. 250ns-7000ns Avg: 326ns Max: 7000ns
Done Dumping histograms
concurrent copying paused:  Sum: 67.235ms 99% C.I. 95us-13710us Avg: 686.071us Max: 23214us
concurrent copying total time: 13.247s mean time: 135.181ms
concurrent copying freed: 4995570 objects with total size 401MB
concurrent copying throughput: 377110/s / 30MB/s
Cumulative bytes moved 89722552
Cumulative objects moved 1732219
Total time spent in GC: 13.247s
Mean GC size throughput: 22MB/s
Mean GC object throughput: 376924 objects/s
Total number of allocations 5494145
Total bytes allocated 322MB
Total bytes freed 296MB
Free memory 18MB
Free memory until GC 18MB
Free memory until OOME 486MB
Total memory 43MB
Max memory 512MB
Zygote space size 604KB
Total mutator paused time: 67.235ms
Total time waiting for GC to complete: 8.968ms
Total GC count: 98
Total GC time: 13.247s
Total blocking GC count: 2
Total blocking GC time: 371.928ms
Histogram of GC count per 10000 ms: 0:85,1:20,2:6,3:5,4:7,6:1,7:1,9:1
Histogram of blocking GC count per 10000 ms: 0:124,1:2
Registered native bytes allocated: 7976669
/system/priv-app/Telecom/oat/arm64/Telecom.odex: speed
/system/priv-app/SettingsProvider/oat/arm64/SettingsProvider.odex: speed
/system/framework/oat/arm64/com.android.location.provider.odex: quicken
/system/priv-app/FusedLocation/oat/arm64/FusedLocation.odex: speed
/system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex: speed
/system/framework/oat/arm64/ethernet-service.odex: speed
/system/framework/oat/arm64/wifi-service.odex: speed
Running non JIT

suspend all histogram:  Sum: 48.762ms 99% C.I. 2.853us-12083.199us Avg:     455.719us Max: 22902us
DALVIK THREADS (123):
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12f002c8 self=0x7b27e0e000
  | sysTid=801 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b2820b4f0
 | state=R schedstat=( 595296653 15941300 423 ) utm=37 stm=21 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7b28111000-0x7b28113000 stackSize=1005KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  native: #00 pc 000000000039d278  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
  native: #01 pc 00000000004645d0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
  native: #02 pc 000000000047b7e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+884)
  native: #03 pc 00000000004741f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureES2_+472)
  native: #04 pc 0000000000473bf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+796)
  native: #05 pc 0000000000473784  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+924)
  native: #06 pc 0000000000448b74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime14DumpForSigQuitERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+196)
  native: #07 pc 0000000000452404  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13HandleSigQuitEv+1684)
  native: #08 pc 0000000000451200  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+356)
  native: #09 pc 0000000000066a4c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
  native: #10 pc 000000000001eb94  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
  (no managed stack frames)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x7313b670 self=0x7b31cbea00
  | sysTid=796 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b3635e9b0
  | state=S schedstat=( 4794795392 1162513029 8541 ) utm=351 stm=127 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ffb433000-0x7ffb435000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x2d0/0x358
  kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0xc8/0x160
  kernel: __sys_trace+0x4c/0x50
  native: #00 pc 00000000000691d4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
  native: #01 pc 000000000001f380  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+48)
  native: #02 pc 0000000000015bd8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+144)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000015ab8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+108)
  native: #04 pc 00000000001112d0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #05 pc 00000000001e43ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:421)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:260)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12f00350 self=0x7b31cbf400
  | sysTid=802 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b27dff4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 98699686 21843387 181 ) utm=8 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7b27cfd000-0x7b27cff000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)    

md line: system_server
Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:8.0.0/OPR5.170623.007/4302479:user/release-keys'
ABI: 'arm64'
Build type: optimized
Zygote loaded classes=4672 post zygote classes=4371
Intern table: 47428 strong; 1959 weak
JNI: CheckJNI is off; globals=3512 (plus 591 weak)
Libraries: /system/lib64/libandroid.so /system/lib64/libandroid_servers.so     /system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so /system/lib64    /libjnigraphics.so /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so /system/lib64/libsoundpool.so     /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so /system/lib64/libwifi-service.so     libjavacore.so libopenjdk.so
```

Errors on arm library. App includes native code compiled with Android NDK. How to debug it?
Any idea on what is wrong, what could I try?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related to use of arm64 on the 6P.  Are you including native code in your app?  If so, try adding following to your `build.gradle`.  Also, check if any related issues in version of NDK you're using

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
    }
```

Comment: app is using ndk r10e (64-bit)

Comment: UPDATE: actually Android.mk already included arm filters as follows:  
TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi
   ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi) GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ARM)
  else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ARMV7)
  else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ARM64)
   else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86)
   else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)  GSTREAMER_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86_64) else $(error Target arch ABI not supported) endif